# Inconsistent GUI layouts in Qt designer and .py after pyuic

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt4, qt-designer

I try to create a form with `Qt designer`. The prototype is:
[image: Figure 1]

I create three `horizontal layouts` in a `vertical layout`, and set `layout stretch` of `vertical layout` to `0, 1, 0`, it makes middle layout looks larger.

After compiling by `pyuic4`, I got:
[image: Figure 2]

Seems like it totally ignored the `layout stretch` I set, even though it was generated correctly in output python code.

Finally I tried to take off the `layout stretch` setting from the layout:
[image: Figure 3]

And compiling again produce the same output.

Is someone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Tried to improve your question adding the images and editing the references but couldn't understand what you meant with "the output is Figure 3, and just like Figure 2", please re-edit/fix if necessary.

Comment: I would try adding some content (or spacer) to the right-middle panel, to see if that helps.

Comment: @KurzedMetal Thanks a lot! My question is that I try to set the layout stretch, but it doesn't work, and the production just like I haven't set anything at all.

Comment: @mdurant You're right!! I love you man!! How about answer it? And I will vote it as right answer.

Comment: By the way, after trying, I found that layout stretch is not work at all. If a piece of panel need to be expand, spacer is a good way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add some content into the right-middle panel. A spacer should work, if you have nothing else.